# На чистом js можно найти предка n-уровня?

Tags: javascript, html

Сейчас, чтобы найти нужного мне предка, я пишу `elem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement`.

1) А можно как-то поизящнее?

2) И другой вопрос: есть такая структура:

```
<table id="some">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input id="myInput" type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Как узнать id table (в данном случае это "some"), если известен input#myInput? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно написать цикл. Но вообще зависит от задачи. И при правильном подходе задача найти родителя не то что бы часто нужна

Answer (score 4):

```
let elem = document.getElementById("myInput");
let elemId = elem.closest('table').id; // table id = some...
```

По сути, через тот же `closest()` можно искать и родителя, тут в зависимости от ситуации варианты рассматривать надо

Answer (score 3):

Есть метод `closest`, который помогает искать родителя по какому-то селектору.

В случае с вашей таблицей:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
const table = input.closest('#some');
if (table) {
  console.log('Parent of input is: ', table);
}
```

```html
<table id="some">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input id="myInput" type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

#### Полезные ссылки

- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Closest` не поддерживается IE, так что в дополнение к другим ответам - полифил:

```js
if (!Element.prototype.closest) {

    Element.prototype.closest = function(css) {
        var node = this;

        while (node) {
            if (node.matches(css)) return node;
            else node = node.parentElement;
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен именно `n` родительский элемент, то можно написать свою функцию:

```js
const nParent = (node, n) => {
  while (node) {
    if (n-- <= 0) return node;
    else node = node.parentElement;
  }
  return null;
}

const x6 = document.getElementById('x6');

console.log(nParent(x6,0));
console.log(nParent(x6,1));
console.log(nParent(x6,2));
console.log(nParent(x6,3));
console.log(nParent(x6,4));
console.log(nParent(x6,5));
console.log(nParent(x6,6));
console.log(nParent(x6,7));
console.log(nParent(x6,8));
```

```html
<div id="x1">
  <div id="x2">
    <div id="x3">
      <div id="x4">
        <div id="x5">
          <div id="x6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```